# how to properly nest a input-group in a control-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Heyo!

I want to append a "09" input-group-addon before my textbox that has a label that are in a form-group.

I tried
1. putting form-group and input-group in the same element - comes out weird
2. nesting input-group in the form group encapsulating the label,span and input - comes out weird
3. nesting input-group in the form group encapsulating the span and input - comes out weird

I've tried googling it and found that I should use #2 (from list i tried to do) but he didn't use a . It seems that the input-group-addon is using the entire height (including the .

```
<div id="TelNumber" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" class="form-group  col-md-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                <label class="control-label">Telephone Number</label>
                <span class="input-group-addon">09</span>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTel" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm"  />
                    </div>
                <p class="help-block"> <asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowTel" runat="server" Text="Show telephone number on profile"   /></p>
            </div>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<div id="TelNumber" runat="server" enableviewstate="False" class="form-group  col-md-3">
  <label class="control-label">Telephone Number</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">09</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <p class="help-block">Show telephone number on profile</p>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/111900

Comment: I tried this (#3) but I don't know why your's work and mine didn't. lol thanks!